# how to append file name in the same file in the continuation with end line of a file without writing file extension along with name

Tags: linux, python

how to append file name in the same file in the continuation with end line of a file without writing file extension along with name.
I have some txt files with one line content and i want to add file name in the same line, at the end, with space, without writing the extension of file name.

Comment: I didn't notice the "python" tag until after answering; don't feel pressured to accept my answer if you actually need an answer in Python. If you don't need it in python, I'd suggest re-tagging the question appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU sed (assumed, given the [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) tag), for `-i` "in-place" editing:

```
for file in *.txt
do
  sed -i "1s/\$/ ${file%%.*}/" "$file"
done
```

With ed:

```
for file in *.txt
do
  printf "%s\n" "1s/\$/ ${file%%.*}/" "wq" | ed -s "$file"
done
```

These leave no space between the end of the line and the filename.

Comment: if I need space between the end of the line and the filename, where should I edit in the code.

Comment: @VivekSharma , see my recent edit.

Comment: Note that using `%%` will remove from the _first_ dot in the filename, whereas using `%` will remove from the _last_ dot.

Comment: @JeffSchaller If I have file with multiple lines how can I print file name at the end with space in all the lines.

Comment: Your original question said `one line content` so that’s what this answer does. Luckily, that feature exists only in the `1` part of the ed/sed search/replace function, so you could just delete that `1`.